# A Picture cannot display in my local computer (however it works in stackblitz)

Tags: react-typescript

Goal:
Display the picture from API by the code that is used at the local hobby project in my local computer.

Problem:
When I use the code from stackblitz to the local computer I get a error about

```
TS2339: Property 'avatar_url' does not exist on type 'never'.

TS2339: Property 'login' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

However, when the same code is used in the stackblitz it works. In other words, it is the same code that is used for stackblitz and local project but it doesn't work in local development computer

What part am I missing in order to the code to be working in my local computer?

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-dah6xw?

Info:
Newbie in react TS

Thank you!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

interface AppProps {}
interface AppState {
  name: string;
}

const apiUrl = 'https://api.github.com/users';

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      var data = await fetch(apiUrl).then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      });
      //console.log(data);
      setItems(data);
      console.log(data);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <div>
          <img src={item.avatar_url} />
          <div>{item.login}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
      ;
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give type to `useState()` like:

```
type User = {
  avatar_url: string;
  login: string;
};

///
const [items, setItems] = React.useState<User[]>([]);
```

I guess your config is very aggressive for linting and TS errors. Normally React doesn't show such errors while compiling.

Comment: It works. Thank you for your help!